# In Orcs Must Die, do guardians count as traps?

Tags: orcs-must-die

In the game *Orcs Must Die*, the achievement **Tunnel Vision** requires that the player

> Win an act 2 or 3 level using a single trap type

For the purposes of this achievement, do guardians count as traps, or can I use both a single type of trap and a guardian (such as an archer)?

Answer (score 6):

As per my experience and [this thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/102600/discussions/0/828935672711212932/):

> you can also use any weapons, magic, guardians and boom barels since they don't count as traps

So no, **guardians do not count as traps**. I believe barricades do not count either. If you're really ambitious, you might try for the no traps achievement at the same time, killing two birds with one stone.

Additionally, beware not to activate any of the traps in the environment because those do count as traps and will negate the achievement.